# How to checkout CAF branch on Cyanogenmod?

Tags: android, git, cyanogenmod, repo

I noticed that Cyanogenmod has branches on some of its git repos named like this: `cm-13.0-caf-8916`. How do I check those out on repo? I tried `repo init -u https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-13.0-caf-8916` but it didn't find it.

Comment: Do you mean how to get to that branch in your local machine?

Comment: @Bustikiller yes I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clone the whole repository into your local machine:

```
git clone https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_hardware_qcom_audio.git
```

Get into the folder

```
cd android_hardware_qcom_audio
```

And checkout to the remote branch:

```
git checkout remotes/origin/cm-13.0-caf-8916
```

Comment: The git repo I found it was here:https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_hardware_qcom_audio/tree/cm-13.0-caf-8916 Is it not for public use or something?

Comment: I have just updated my answer. The repo is for public use, you can download it just executing the commands I posted. However, if you want to develop some code, you should better fork the project, commit your changes and create a pull request.

Comment: CyanogenMod uses gerrit @ http://review.cyanogenmod.org for submitting changes.  Pull requests on github are automatically rejected and you will receive a message indicating that you should submit your changes to gerrit instead.  You can find info on submitting changes at https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_using_gerrit